# "xq" in Internet slang/abbreviations

Tags: traducción, abreviaturas, jerga-internet

In informal chat conversations online, I have seen Spanish speakers write the abbreviation "xq." What does this stand for, and why?

Comment: I'd suggest you not to use them, It's a bad habit and mostly used by teenagers

Comment: There is a universal law that whenever you write against incorrect usage of language, you will invariably make a usage faux pas of your own for everybody to see. For instance some people would regard  the omission of a full stop/period at the end of a sentence to be a bad habit. (-;

Comment: I do it when I am in a hurry, texting, lazy or feel comfortable enough with someone to use it. If is something formal I would never use it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It essentially means porque

x is widely recognized as the multiplication sign. To say it one says por.

> x = Por

and q is the abbreviation of que. Being just a q there are no words I can think of that are monosyllables and that start with q. So it is safe to assume it is que.

> q = que
>
> xq = porque

Comment: "Porque" no lleva tilde. "¿Por qué ...?" sí la lleva

Comment: «xk» means the same as «xq», just as «k» means the same as «q» and both mean «que» (or «qué»). But «xD» has nothing to do with «por». Texting is hard.

Comment: xD resembles [this smiley](http://www.todoparamsn.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/xd.png).

Comment: Porqué lleva tilde cuando se utiliza la forma de la pregunta "por qué" en forma indirecta, como sustantivo. Son tres formas diferentes. Ejemplo: "Le preguntaron el porqué de su vestimenta inadecuada"

Answer (score 21):

In SMS/chat slang:

- **xq**, **xk**, **pq** means *"porque"* or *"por qué"*;
- **x** means *"por"*, because it looks like × (multiplication sign);
- **q** or **k** means *"que"*;
- **xf** means *"por fa(vor)"*
- **qtl** or **ktl** means *"que tal"*;
- **qtpsa** or **ktpsa** means *"que te pasa"*;
- **=** means *"igual"*;
- **+** means *"mas"* or *"más"*;
- **-** means *"menos"*;
- **s** means *"es"*;
- **l** means *"el"*;
- **d** means *"de"*;

etc.

Example:

```
"ktl?"
"+ o -"
"xk? ktpsa?"
```

Comment: It's harder to write slang than regular spanish! :P

Comment: It's hard to write slang in any language... except owns.