# Meaning of "teneis tema q t kemas"

Tags: traducción, significado, jerga-internet

What does it mean:

```
 Pero teneis tema q t kemas o no?
```

I received this message from a person that lives in Basque country, but I see there some Spanish words. I don't understand anyway...

Comment: We are not a translation service. We are happy to help you understand a Spanish phrase or sentence, but you must first demonstrate that you have attempted your own translation, and you must ask specific questions. Many questions on this site (such as [this one](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/583/12)) will already provide clues to your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is text-messaging, so the spelling is unique (economy of characters). It would be saying

> Pero tenéis tema que te quemas, o no?

I figure that that slang *tema que te quemas* uses that rhyme to sound catchy and, without any context, I would assume that there something going on among a group of friends, for example, that has everyone rattled or unsettled.

You could have *tema* with **one** somebody if you where having an affair or an ongoing intimate relationship. With one group it could be a discussion or situation.

That *que te quemas* could actually be translated literally like to stress that the situation is **hot**, either because is interesting, because people are getting to each other throats or the like.

Comment: En Madrid, al menos, *tener tema* significa *disponer de metanfetaminas* (¿o era cocaína?  como no soy junkie...), no sé si en País Vasco llegó a tener el mismo significado.

Comment: @guifa, pues la verdad es que cuadra, como _tener mercancía muy buena..._ o tener un montón. Puede ser, no he frecuentado esos círculos, así que no sé si se emplea esa jerga o no.